# performSegue pushes next view controller into unwanted view hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm building a navigation-based app, in which you can navigate with bottom tab and each tabs have their own navigation stacks.
Most of the part works as expected, but one particular tab behaves unexpectedly.

What's happening is:

After navigating through several view controllers, let's say [A] [B] [C]  and [D], the next controller [E] suddenly goes off the navigation stack.
When it happens the view looks like presented modally, and the navigation stack looks like this.

```
(lldb) po [[[UIWindow keyWindow] rootViewController] _printHierarchy]

<MyApp.CRTabBarController 0x112026800>, state: disappeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x111e1fa00> not in the window
   | <UINavigationController 0x112027a00>, state: disappeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x111e23f50> not in the window
   |    | <MyApp.X1_ViewController 0x111d12490>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x111e32d70> not in the window
   |    |    | <MyApp.InsideX1_ViewController 0x112096200>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x111e35d90> not in the window
   | <UINavigationController 0x11200aa00>, state: disappeared, view: (view not loaded)
   |    | <MyApp.X2_ViewController 0x111d22360>, state: disappeared, view: (view not loaded)
   | <UINavigationController 0x11205a200>, state: disappeared, view: (view not loaded)
   |    | <MyApp.X3_Controller 0x11205a800>, state: disappeared, view: (view not loaded)
   | <UINavigationController 0x112059600>, state: disappeared, view: (view not loaded)
   |    | <MyApp.X4_ViewController 0x111e0cea0>, state: disappeared, view: (view not loaded)
   | <UINavigationController 0x112058e00>, state: disappeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x111d50370> not in the window
   |    | <MyApp.A_ViewController 0x111d25f70>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x116e0ad90> not in the window
   |    |    | <MyApp.PageViewController 0x112891400>, state: disappeared, view: <_UIPageViewControllerContentView 0x113feb0a0> not in the window
   |    |    |    | <MyApp.InnerPageViewController 0x111ee3bf0>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x111e6e000> not in the window
   |    | <MyApp.B_ViewController 0x113ee8280>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x116e37cf0> not in the window
   |    | <MyApp.C_Controller 0x118f06f10>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x113ee46f0> not in the window
   |    | <MyApp.D_ViewController 0x116e5f580>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x118f2fe70> not in the window
   + <E_ViewController 0x116ecff30>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x111ee43f0>, presented with: <_UIFullscreenPresentationController 0x116e13420>
```

The four navigation controllers from the top are the inactive tabs which are not the interest here. In the navigation of the last tab you can see `A_ to D_ - ViewController's`. Then, `E_ViewController` is in the different navigation hierarchy, which is the problem here.

The code is pretty straight forward, `D_ViewController` just invokes `performSegue` like this.

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goto_E", sender: self)
```

The `Segue` setting is also pretty normal, I think. It just specify the id and "Show" as the style.  The `Segue` is connected from `D_ViewController`to `E_ViewController` so it can be referred as a `performSegue's` identifier arg.

[image]

Has anybody had this kind of experience? Any guess about the possible reason?

Comment: Is the segue from D to E the same as the other ones in the chain say B to C or C to D?

Comment: Yes, they are all same.  I compared visually by clicking the segues and nothing changed except for the identifier.

Comment: And they go B_ViewController to C_ViewController, C_ViewController to D_ViewController in the same way?

Comment: I use performSegue for all these transition, and transitions A to B, B to C and C to D all perform with the same sliding effect. And as I wrote in my original post, controllers(A~D) are stuck in the proper navigation stack.

Answer (score 1):

//Remove segue and instantiate

```
extension UIViewController {

     class func instantiate(fromStoryboard name: String, id: String) -> Self? {
         return instantiateHelper(fromStoryboard: name, id: id)
     }

     private class func instantiateHelper<T>(fromStoryboard name: String, id: String) -> T? {
         let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: name, bundle: nil)
         let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: id) as? T
         return controller
     }
}
```

Use:-

```
 guard let vc = ViewController.instantiate(fromStoryboard: "Main", id: "ViewController") else { return }
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Why?  What is the reason for removing the segue and using instantiation instead?  Should that be done for everything and then segues never used?

Comment: Looks like a good workaround. The point is to grab VC from Storyboard and push it directly to the navigation controller, right?  Let me give it a shot.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Many time segue doesn't work properly. So, it's better to instantiate.

Comment: A segue should only not work properly if something is setup incorrect.  As long as everything is coded correctly there shouldn't be a problem.  It's definitely not better to instantiate as that negates a lot of the functionality of storyboards (and large parts of the WWDC talks).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, but I've solved it by myself.
It's embarrassing to say, but the reason was pretty silly, that it was calling `popViewController` right before calling `performSegue`.

This pop call was there because of the heritage of my view structure change, and it was hard to notice because written in the separated place.

Although it wasn't a direct answer but the approach that instantiating directly from Storyboard was useful to clarify the issue.  Thanks, Pratyush.

But it was completely unexpected that popping view controller before pulling the segue results to this kind of behavior. 
Hope this can be a hint to other people's issues.